# Updating JFrame JLabel image path

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am reading a file path from a txt file that is constantly being created and deleted by another program, about once a second.  The file path is that of an image which is then displayed in a `JLabel` inside a `JFrame`.  The file path is read by the same thread that handles the frame.

My very crude method for updating the label is to put the thread on an endless loop with the frame being deleted and created every time

```
frame.dispose; 
new mainDisplay();
```

This is not too good because of many reasons I am sure but the main one affecting me being that users see the frame being closed and opened every few seconds.

Could someone suggest a better way?

Comment: Call [`setText()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setText(java.lang.String)) on the jLabel to update its text?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to rebuild the whole application just to refresh a label. As already mentioned in comments `JLabel.setText` should be sufficient.

However, make sure you update Swing components on *Event Dispatch Thread*. Do not create endless loops, Swing is event based. You are running a risk of blocking *Event Dispatch Thread*. Read more in [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) tutorial. Also, do not carry heavy long running tasks on EDT.

Use Swing timer for periodic tasks that update UI on EDT. See [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for details and examples. Also, look at [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for long running tasks.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution might be using `WatchService` to track updates to the file that's constantly getting deleted and recreated.  Have it handle events for "file created" and then you don't have to worry about your event firing off and the file being deleted mid-read (however rare that might be, unexplained I/O errors are still a pain).

Oracles doc about it:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Further I agree with Aqua's assessment of just setting the text label instead of rebuilding the whole JFrame.